# JOIN таблиц из двух разных бд на codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

В codeigniter запросы к бд выполняются таким способом: `$this->db->query` или `$someDB->query`, но что если я хочу обратиться сразу к двум бд и объединить таблицы JOIN'ом?

На чистом PHP можно использовать `mysqli_connect` и написать какой-нибудь такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2
```

Но есть ли способ сделать это на codeigniter?

Comment: Мне кинули ссылку на несколько примеров: [http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-join-query](http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-join-query), но пока я не пойму как это использовать для запроса к двум бд сразу.

Comment: в инете полно инфы по этому поводу.вот первое попавшееся - http://www.maiboroda.ru/webmaster/ispolzuem-dve-bazy-v-codeigniter-2-1-0-odnovremenno/

Comment: читал эту статью. Там про то, как обратиться к двум базам сразу. Это можно использовать для того, чтобы написать два SELECT'а, но не JOIN

Comment: это примерно то, что я имел в виду, когда писал вверху `$someDB->query`

Comment: похоже мне больше не нужно JOIN'ить две базы, хотя всё ещё интересно как это можно было бы сделать

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал в таком случае заворачиваться, сделал 2 запроса и полученные массивы смерджил ну или как-то обработал.

Comment: ну да, я так и делал в принципе. просто интересно можно ли это как-то сделать через JOIN

Comment: Ну в таком случае используйте сырой запрос. Это же Active Record) Он дает возможность исполнять raw query)
`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2")` - вот так и сделать не пробовали?
Если мне не изменяет память, давно я конечно с AR не работал, но вот так он возвращает foo из инициализированной таблицы
`$rows = $this->db->get('foo')->row_array(); `
А так 
`$rows = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `foo`")->row_array();`
Делает в принципе тоже самое, только с большей гибкостью.

Comment: `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2")` - пробовал раньше, выдавал ошибку: `pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: relation 'db2.table2' does not exist`. Я так понял, что с помощью `$this->db->query` он коннектится только к базе, которая прописана по дефолту. Или может я что-то делаю не так. Второй запрос ещё не пробовал, надо будет попробовать

Comment: В конце концов, если уж ничего не поможет, напишите себе либо хэлпер, либо расширение в виде статического метода для active record. Это решит проблему. Там отсилы 5-7 строчек выйдет. Можно еще на гитхабе поискать. 100% кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой.